# codeigniter, Ion, Bootstrap

Tags: codeigniter, templates, ion-auth

I am working on implementing the Ion Auth library into codeigniter with a bootstrap template.

Now the auth.php conroller file is calling the views but I want those views to be put into my controls so i can show them in my mail template like this:

```
<?php echo $content; ?>
```

My auth.php file calls the views like this originally:

```
$this->_render_page('auth/login', $this->data);
```

But i would like to call them this way:

```
$this->load->view('template/user', array("content" => $this->_render_page('auth/login',$this->data array())));
```

This doesn't seem to work. My auto/login page appears above the template/user, but it should appear inside.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem?

Comment: can you show more of hte code on the auth.php, does this file return at the end or just echo out, rather, what does _render_page() do?

Comment: $this->load->view('auth/login', $this->data); will work

Answer (score 0):

To do this edit your code as follows `$this->load->view('template/user', array("content" => $this->_render_page('auth/login',$this->data array(), TRUE)));` Go to ion_auth auth controller and correct the following error

Original function

```
`function _render_page($view, $data=null, $render=false)
{

    $this->viewdata = (empty($data)) ? $this->data: $data;

    $view_html = $this->load->view($view, $this->viewdata, $render);

    if (!$render) return $view_html;
}`
```

Modified function

`function _render_page($view, $data=null, $render=false)
    {

```
    $this->viewdata = (empty($data)) ? $this->data: $data;

    $view_html = $this->load->view($view, $this->viewdata, $render);

    if ($render) return $view_html;
}`
```

The error is found in the final if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party on this one, but if you manage your CI templates the way that I do, then this is an easy way to update the `_render_page` function in ion auth:

All of my content gets pulled into a single template file that look like so:

```
<?php $this->load->view('includes/header'); ?>

<?php $this->load->view($contents); ?>

<?php $this->load->view('includes/footer'); ?>
```

In the case where ion auth wants to just refresh the page, like so,

`redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');`

I use the following lines instead.

```
$redirectString = 'auth/login';
$view_params['contents'] = $redirectString;
$this->load->view('site_template',$view_params);
```

Then in the case where ion auth wants to use its `_render_page` function, I leave those functions alone, but updated the `_render_page` function itself to this:

```
function _render_page($view, $data=null, $render=false)
{
    $this->viewdata = (empty($data)) ? $this->data: $data;      
    $this->viewdata['contents'] = $view;                
    $view_html = $this->load->view('site_template', $this->viewdata, $render);
    if (!$render) return $view_html;
}
```

The main change it where I insert the general site_template into the internal view call in the `_render_page` function